# jquery - Ignoring '\n' string when pasting an Input type="hidden" value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm doing a "copy to clipboard" using Zclip (http://www.steamdev.com/zclip/). It's copying correctly, but I'm trying to improve it.
this is my html code:

```
<input type="hidden" value="value 01: 789456123 \n value 02: 547812321 \n value 03: 789456423 \n ">
<button id="copy-button">copy</button>
```

and the js:

```
$("#copy-button").zclip({
     path: "ZeroClipboard.swf",
     copy: function(){
        return $(this).prev().val();
        }
    });
```

I wish to replace "\n" to break lines when I paste it. Here some pics.

[image: alert]

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "ignore"? What is the expected paste result? It's not clear from those images.

Comment: Do you want line breaks instead of `\n`s?

Comment: Yes. I expect line breaks.

Comment: I really think, this depends on the system you are pasting it in. If it is window, you might try to regex it into \r\n, but I don't know, if this is going to work. You will probably have to parse your clipboard-content afterwards, depending on your system and program you paste it in.

Comment: I'm really, really confused as your alert picture is having line-breaks but you're saying it's not appearing line-breaks...

Answer (score 1):

Instead of placing JavaScript style line breaks put html style line breaks or actual line breaks (they are legal)

```js
alert(document.querySelector('input').value);
```

```html
<input type="hidden" value="value 01: 789456123 &#x0a; value 02: 547812321 &#x0a; value 03: 789456423 &#x0a; ">
```

```js
alert(document.querySelector('input').value);
```

```html
<input type="hidden" value="value 01: 789456123 
value 02: 547812321 
value 03: 789456423">
```

Comment: However what seems odd is that JS-style line breaks are displayed correctly in the browser but at the end of the day are copied as a simple text.

Comment: @VisioN I'm not sure what you mean. Where are they displayed correctly in the browser?

Comment: @JLRishe In the browser modal window saying "Copied to clipboard: ..." on the first screen.

Comment: @VisioN That is odd. I suspect there is some detail that OP is leaving out.

Comment: @vbotio Try using `&#x0d;&#x0a;` instead of just `&#x0a;`. Notepad doesn't display LF newlines when they occur on their own.

Comment: @JLRishe still not working. Its not showing \n or &#x0d;&#x0a; anymore, but it still not breaking the line.

Comment: @vbotio what do you want to use the text for? The line break is there but notpad cannot render it.

Comment: I'll use it to send an email. I tried to paste it on another text editors, Word, Excel, Outlook, sublime text, brackets

Comment: @vbotio if you set up a live demo of it i'll check it out.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it using javascript

```
    $("#copy-button").zclip({
    path: "ZeroClipboard.swf",
    copy: function(){
        // return $("#teste").html();
        return document.getElementById('teste').value.trim().replace(/(<br>)/g,' \r\n');
        },
    });
```

It worked perfectly. Thanks to everyone! :)